# How to use dynamic property name in predefined yup schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I want to pass dynamic property name to predefined yup schema based on array of items, generate schema and combined all of them as single validationSchema to pass it in Formik component.

e.g.,
for the below snippet i want to get it replaced {dynamic-property-name} based on myArray = ['name1', 'name2'.......];

Predefined schema :

```
Yup.object().shape({
        {dynamic-property-name}: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    });
```

expected output schema:

```
export const dynamicSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name1: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    name2: Yup.string().required('Required'),
});
```